# Spring Rest Controller - Can I allow allow CORS in the interceptor?

Tags: spring, cors, spring-restcontroller

I have an interceptor:

```
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor());
    }
```

Can I add my CORS configuration in the RequestInterceptor.java above? Like this:

```
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter
   {
   ...

   public boolean preHandle(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler) throws Exception {
       ...
       ...
       if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:9090");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "4800");
        }
        ...
        return true;
    }
 }
```

I do not want any of these methods because for some reason they are not working for me:

```
@CrossOrigin
   OR
WebMvcConfigurerAdapter -> addCorsMapping()
```

The only thing works for me is having a CORSFilter and mapping it in the web.xml. But that got me thinking that Interceptors are also kind of Filter, aren't they? Then why to add a Filter AND an interceptor when interceptor itself will do.

Anyway, I tried with the above piece of code and my requests are landing in the server and the rest controller method is running, but I see this response on my ReactJs page:

```
SEC7120: Origin http://localhost:9090 not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

What am I missing? Is there anything else I have to do in the RequestInterceptor.java class for CORS?

Thanks.